# How to redirect stderr and stdout to a file and a screen in the same time for Python script?

Tags: python, redirect, stdout, stderr

I send files to my ftp server with this code. I would like to have error log on screen and the same traceback and error in my log file. For now, in my log file is only error name. How to put stdout and stderr in the file and on the screen in the same time?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import ftplib
import sys


# FTP server login data
ftpserver_ip = '192.168.0.100'
username = 'uname'
password = 'upass'

# If there is command line argument, the first one is our file to upload
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    upload_file = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print('No input file')
    sys.exit()

def ftpsend():
    try:
        # ftp server running on 'ftpserver_ip' on port 21
        session = ftplib.FTP(ftpserver_ip, username, password)
        file = open(upload_file, 'rb')
        session.storbinary('STOR '+upload_file, file)
        file.close()
        session.quit()
    except Exception as err:
        with open('error.log', 'w') as ferr:
            print(err)
            ferr.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            ferr.write('\n')
            ferr.write(str(err))
        return None

    with open('OK.log', 'w') as fok:
        fok.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        fok.write(" OK")
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "OK")

ftpsend()
```

If everything went well, file OK.log should be created. If an error occur, file `error.log' should be created with this content eg.:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'simple_table.pd'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp-send.py", line 35, in ftpsend
    file = open(upload_file, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'simple_table.pd'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Don't bother doing it inside the python script.  Instead, when you call it, pipe the streams through `tee`

Comment: eg. `./my-script 2>&1 | tee output-file`

Comment: I can't. This is going to be run in clipper/win cmd.

Comment: In Windows you do that like this: `myscript.py > output_file 2>&1`

Comment: If there is an error, file should have one name and if there is no exception, file shuold have another name. Can't do that via cmd